# Why in docker-compose I should write full path to volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

I have some confusing moments with docker-compose volumes (In docker windows server (container)).
I wrote the next configuration

```
volumes:
  - "C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/admin-stat-logs:C:/app/Logs"
```

and why it so necessary to write the full path to the volume?

if I write:

```
volumes:
  - "admin-logs:C:/app/Logs"
```

it generates the error
ERROR: Named volume "admin-logs:C:/app/Logs:rw" is used in service "admin-stat-table" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.

why does it happen?

**UPDATE**

let me show what I mean(I made wrong explonation). In an image, we have a short announcement from the official documentation.

[image]

I write the same in my case:

```
volumes:
  - admin-logs:C:/app/Logs
```

I create volume before by the terminal. When I start docker-compose up I get the next error

> **ERROR: Named volume "admin-stat-logs:C:/app/Logs:rw" is used in service "admin-stat-table" but no declaration was found in the volumes section.**

I made a mistake in the first case, it's a simple mount to a folder, sorry for my misunderstanding.

```
volumes:
  - "C:/ProgramData/Docker/volumes/admin-stat-logs:C:/app/Logs"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use a full path. You can use a relative path to the location of your docker-compose.yml file.

When you write `admin-logs:C:/app/Logs`, you're telling docker-compose to use a volume named `admin-logs`. If you want to use a folder where you docker-compose is located, you can write `./admin-logs:C:/app/Logs`.

If you plan to use a separated docker volume, you need to first define it in the docker-compose.yml. Here's an example covering both cases:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  mytest:
    image: ubuntu:18.04
    volumes:
      - "mymnt:/mnt/volume"
      - "./mymnt_on_host:/mnt/mounted_folder"
volumes:
  mymnt:
```

You'll need a `mymnt_on_host` directory in the folder where the docker-compose.yml is located.

For more info about this topic, you can check the [reference guide](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) for the docker-compose.yml

UPDATE:

If you plan to use an already created volume in your docker-compose, you can use `external: true` in the volumes definition.

e.g.

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  mytest:
    image: ubuntu:18.04
    volumes:
      - "mymnt:/mnt/volume"
      - "./mymnt_on_host:/mnt/mounted_folder"
volumes:
  mymnt:
  my_existing_volume:
    external: true
```

Now if you start this, docker-compose won't try to generate `my_existing_volume` but it'll expect to find it already on the machine.

For more info check [external](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external) reference.

Comment: But you don't need to write the full path to use the volume, right? and I should because if no I get an error. And the question was: why I get an error if I write just the name of the volume, why it so necessary?

Comment: you don't need the full path. as I wrote you can use a relative path to the location where is the docker-compose.yml. In your case, you were trying to use a volume that was not defined.

Comment: ok, I think I understand what you meant. You get that error because the volume declaration has to be present in the docker-compose.yml. You cannot simply create it beforehand and start the containers.

Comment: lulz, that's the first time I get the F. Can you accept the answer?

Answer (score -1):

Can you show your version value in the `docker-compose.yml` file. It should be `version: '3'` or `version: '3.5'`. Probably you have `version: '2'`

Comment: The volume syntax is identical in all versions of the Compose YAML file (and mirrors the `docker run -v` option, which also has basically never changed).

Comment: @DavidMaze correct, but I had similar problem and as I remebmer, just changing it to version 3 fixed.